# How HereDocument works

Tags: bash, shell, sh, sendmail, heredoc

Can someone please explain how the below command works? Ignore the sendmail command switches as such - I know how that works. I want to know how the rest of the command works i.e. the here-document (without termination), cat reading from stdin and how it gets piped to sendmail.

```
SEND_MAIL()
{
`cat -  $body <<HERE | /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t
From: $SENDER
To: $RECEIVER
Subject: $SUBJECT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
MIME-Version: 1.0`
}
```

Update:
To answer some of the confusions, above code was written by someone else and surprisingly it does work. The author of the code simply executes the function and it successfully sends mail to the recipient with the content of $body.

Comment: It shouldn't work at all, since you are missing the closing delimiter for the here-doc.

Comment: Why is the whole command block in backticks? It Wouldn't work without those. Add the HERE terminator, and see if you can do without those, as they are currently the hackery that's making it try.

Comment: @chepner - it does work, probably because of the backticks like Jon said.

Comment: If `sendmail` produced any output, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

So trick here is that `-` is special to `cat`. It makes `cat` read "a file" from standard input. The here document writes the literal lines to `cat`'s standard input, so the effect is to concatenate the literal lines on the front of the file `$body`.

Bash appears to accept a missing here-document delimiter within backticks, though it does whinge:

```
$ `cat <<HERE
echo foo
`
bash: warning: here-document at line 1 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `HERE')
foo
$
```

Those backticks aren't what you wanted, by the way. Try

```
SEND_MAIL()
{
cat -  $body <<HERE | /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t
From: $SENDER
To: $RECEIVER
Subject: $SUBJECT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
MIME-Version: 1.0
HERE
}
```

Comment: The missing delimiter will cause other errors, though; in the given example, the function definition is never terminated, because the closing `}` is still part of the here document.

Comment: @chepner Surprisingly, the backticks appear to be limiting the extent of the here doc. Try  foo () {
\`cat <<HERE
echo foo
\`; }
Those backticks really shouldn't be there though. I'm pretty sure he didn't want to execute the output of sendmail!

Comment: Technically, it's the end of the input that terminates the here document; the backtick simply delimits the command substitution.

Comment: @chepner I'm sure you are right technically. But try  \`cat <<HERE\n
echo foo\n
\` from a prompt...

Comment: Thanks @Jon for the explanation. But the function actually sends mail with the content of $body, not what you mentioned "so the effect is to concatenate the literal lines on the front of the file $body". And the content of the $body variable is some HTML.